# qcompleter поиск НЕ с первого символа

Tags: qt

```
   componentsCompleter = new QCompleter(componentsModel,this);
   componentsCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
   componentsCompleter->setCompletionColumn(componentsModel->fieldIndex("item"));
```

как сделать чтобы поиск был не только с начала строки. Т.е. если я пишу "force" он выкидывает строчку "let the force be with you"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [справке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop):

> If filterMode is set to `Qt::MatchStartsWith`, only those entries that
>   start with the typed characters will be displayed. `Qt::MatchContains`
>   will display the entries that contain the typed characters, and
>   `Qt::MatchEndsWith` the ones that end with the typed characters.

что в переводе:

> Если режим фильтрации установлен в `Qt::MatchStartsWith`, то будут
>   выданы элементы, начинающиеся с искомой строки. Если
>   `Qt::MatchContains`, то содержащие искомую. Ну а если
>   `Qt::MatchEndsWith`, то только те из них, что заканчиваются на оную.

Соответственно, если требуется поиск строк, содержащих искомый набор символов, то ставим флаг `Qt::MatchContains`:

```
componentsCompleter = new QCompleter(componentsModel,this);
componentsCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
componentsCompleter->setFilterMode(Qt::MatchContains);
componentsCompleter->setCompletionColumn(componentsModel->fieldIndex("item"));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сильно не ругайте)